# STM32 MPPT ADC measurements to slow?

Tags: c, stm32

Good afternoon,

I'm making an MPPT but unfortunately I'm having some problems with the software.
I set the STM32F302's ADC to 72MHz with DMA. I also use a 500uS timer interrupt to convert my ADC/DMA measurements to voltages and currents. These calculations cost 100us. Unfortunately, when I debug my MPPT algorithm (every 50ms), I find out that every time the ADC/DMA is too slow?? I'm getting old readings that cause my MPPT to collapse all over again at the top. Who can help me?

[Timer interrupt ADC/DMA calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHZ6M.png)

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  MODULE DEPENDENCY                                       */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
#include "analog.h"

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  DEFINITIONS AND MACROS                                  */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  TYPE DEFINITIONS                                        */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
#define ANALOG_NUMBERS_CHANNEL          6
#define NUMBER_ANALOG_CHANNEL_AVERAGE       10

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  PROTOTYPES OF NOT EXPORTED FUNCTIONS                    */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/


/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  EXPORTED / IMPORTED GLOBAL VARIABLES                    */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  NOT EXPORTED GLOBAL VARIABLES                           */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
static uint16_t ADC_DMA_BUFF[ANALOG_NUMBERS_CHANNEL * NUMBER_ANALOG_CHANNEL_AVERAGE];

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                    EXPORTED FUNCTIONS                                    */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
void Analog_Init(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = ANALOG_NUMBERS_CHANNEL;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_61CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_10;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_6;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA1_Channel1;
  hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
  hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
  hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
  hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
  hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
  hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
  if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  __HAL_LINKDMA(&hadc1,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

  if(HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED) != HAL_OK)
  {
      Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)ADC_DMA_BUFF, ANALOG_NUMBERS_CHANNEL * NUMBER_ANALOG_CHANNEL_AVERAGE) != HAL_OK)
  {
      Error_Handler();
  }
}

uint16_t Analog_GetChannel(int channel)
{
    uint32_t adc_sum;
    int i;

    adc_sum = 0;
    if(channel < ANALOG_NUMBERS_CHANNEL )
    {
        for(i=0; i<NUMBER_ANALOG_CHANNEL_AVERAGE; i++)
            adc_sum += ADC_DMA_BUFF[channel+i*ANALOG_NUMBERS_CHANNEL];
    }
    else
        return 1;

    return adc_sum/NUMBER_ANALOG_CHANNEL_AVERAGE;
}



/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  NOT EXPORTED FUNCTIONS                                  */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
```

For the tests I use a simple algorithm that decides on the basis of the power whether the duty cycle should be increased or decreased

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  MODULE DEPENDENCY                                       */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
#include "mppt.h"
#include "delay.h"

#include "control.h"
/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  DEFINITIONS AND MACROS                                  */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  TYPE DEFINITIONS                                        */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  PROTOTYPES OF NOT EXPORTED FUNCTIONS                    */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
static void MPPT_PerturbAndObserve(void);

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  EXPORTED / IMPORTED GLOBAL VARIABLES                    */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  NOT EXPORTED GLOBAL VARIABLES                           */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
static uint16_t mppt_duty_cycle;

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                    EXPORTED FUNCTIONS                                    */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
/****************************************************************************/
void MPPT_Init(void)
/****************************************************************************/
{
    mppt_duty_cycle = 0;
    Control_PWMOutputDisable();
}

/****************************************************************************/
void MPPT_Function(void)
/****************************************************************************/
{
    static MPPTStateType currentmode;
    static uint32_t lastsweep;

    uint16_t Vin;
    uint16_t Vout;

    if (Delay_Tick1ms(&lastsweep, 50))
    {
        switch(currentmode)
        {
            case MpptState_init:
                currentmode = MpptState_PO;
                mppt_duty_cycle = 1000 - (1000 *   (float)Control_GetRegulatedInputVoltage()/(float)Control_GetRegulatedOutputVoltage()));
                PWM_SetDuty(mppt_duty_cycle);
                Control_PWMOutputEnable();
            break;

            case MpptState_PO:
                MPPT_PerturbAndObserve();
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*                  NOT EXPORTED FUNCTIONS                                  */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
static void MPPT_PerturbAndObserve(void)
{
    static float best_power;

    float current = Control_GetRegulatedInputCurrent() * 0.001f;
    float voltage = Control_GetRegulatedInputVoltage() * 0.001f;
    float power = current * voltage;

    if (power > best_power)
    {
        best_power = power;
        mppt_duty_cycle += 2;
    }

    else
    {
        best_power = power;
        mppt_duty_cycle -= 2;
    }
    
    best_power = power;
    PWM_SetDuty(mppt_duty_cycle);
}
```

Comment: I can assure you that ADC is not too slow.  I would not recommend HAL for this.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any synchronisation between the ADC, your 500us timer, and your main loop. The DMA could be mid-way through your array when you start reading it, for example. Would suggest not using circular-buffer mode, just read one set of readings, process that, then start again.

Comment: To add to above, if you absolutely need continuous readings for your algorithm to work, abandon the 500us timer, and use the "half complete" and "fully complete" interrupts from the DMA. You can process one half of the array while the DMA fills the other half.

Comment: Your `MPPT_PerturbAndObserve()` function sets `best_power = power;` in three separate places. I'm sure this can't be right.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

@pmacfarlane I was still working on the algorithm. This has now been successful. It works for 90% because unfortunately the algorithm is about the MPP and will hang between 2 points. This seems to be the duty cycle step size and the measurements because if I manually change the duty cycle in a written test mode then this works correctly. For now that is not a problem and I first have to make sure that I get 3 parallel MPPTs working. Unfortunately I suffer from backflow current now when I want to connect 2 MPPTs together. I have to look into how to fix this. If you have a tip I really appreciate it